# Web scraping com BeautifulSoup - find_next não retorna o texto

Tags: html, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Quero extrair o texto do trecho abaixo:

```
<div class="matchDate renderMatchDateContainer" data-kickoff="1583784000000">Mon 9 Mar 2020</div>
```

o texto seria "Mon 9 Mar 2020". Porém quando faço:

```
date = match_bar[0].find_next('div', {'class': 'matchDate renderMatchDateContainer'})
```

Tenho como retorno o seguinte, sem o texto em si:

```
<div class="matchDate renderMatchDateContainer" data-kickoff="1583784000000"></div>
```

Quanto acrescento '.text' o retorno é vazio. Não tenho muita experiencia com HTML.

**UPDATE**:

percebi que quando executo o códgio:

```
my_url = 'https://www.premierleague.com/match/{}'.format(i)
client = urlopen(my_url)
page_html = client.read()
```

O trecho em questão já aprece assim, sem o texto:

```
<div class="matchDate renderMatchDateContainer" data-kickoff="1583784000000"></div>
```

Enquanto no navegador eu consigo ver o texto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia ajudar? Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agora que tenho acesso ao link compreendi melhor qual é seu problema e vamos falar sobre ele.

O motivo pelo qual você não está conseguindo é devido o site ser renderizado ao carregar a página, fazendo uma requisição para obter o código HTML ele volta com apenas o corpo HTML não composto pois ele só é preenchido com o carregamento da página.

Vamos a solução, uma das possíveis soluções e a melhor e que eu te recomendo é a utilização da biblioteca de automatização selenium e para consumir o menor processamento possível vamos adicionar um argumento para que ele carregue a página de modo oculto, assim não exibirá o que está sendo aberto pelo navegador automatizado, com ela será possível carregar a página e então obter o corpo HTML já preenchido com os valores.

Recomendo fortemente caso nunca tenha trabalhado com o selenium ler a documentação, pois você precisará baixar o driver e editar o caminho descrito no "executable_path".
Vou deixar um código abaixo com a solução do problema:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

def obterCodigoFonte(url):
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'.\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(url)
    return driver.page_source

def processarCodigoFonte(cf):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(cf, 'html.parser')
    getValueFromDiv = soup.find('div', class_='matchDate renderMatchDateContainer')
    return getValueFromDiv.text


url = 'https://www.premierleague.com/match/46889'
codigoFonte = obterCodigoFonte(url)
print(processarCodigoFonte(codigoFonte))
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tudo bem?

Se sua intenção é extrair o trecho de uma div específica a maneira que você está tentando extrair a informação está errada, basta que você utilize a função find do bs4 especificando qual é a classe dessa div.

Vou disponibilizar um exemplo de como ficaria o código:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class='matchDate renderMatchDateContainer' 
          data-kickoff='1583784000000'>Mon 9 Mar 2020</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

getValueFromDiv = soup.find('div', class_='matchDate renderMatchDateContainer').text

print(getValueFromDiv)
```

o resultado desse input foi:

```
Mon 9 Mar 2020
```

Comment: Olá Jefferon, beleza?
Aqui o resultado deste mesmo input foi em branco. No trecho a seguir encontro o mesmo problema: "<strong class="renderKOContainer" data-kickoff="1583584200000">09:30</strong>". O texto '09:30' não aparece. Em techos como o seguinte, funciona normalmente: "<div class="attendance hide-m">Att: 53,323</div>"

Comment: Atualizei o post com novas informações.